# C# - how to get a specific value from a xml

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I know this question has been asked a lot but I couldn't find one that suited me.
I'm trying to get the weather from BBC Weather using their RSS feed.
In this RSS feed, I'am trying to get the value of the second title (**).

Rss Feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>BBC Weather - Observations for  Hampstead, GB</title>
    <link>https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2647553</link>
    <description>Latest observations for Hampstead from BBC Weather, </description>
    <language>en</language>
    <copyright>Copyright: (C) British Broadcasting Corporation,</copyright>
    <pubDate>Wed, 30 Oct 2019 14:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
    <dc:date>2019-10-30T14:00:00Z</dc:date>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dc:rights>Copyright: (C) British Broadcasting Corporation, </dc:rights>
    <atom:link rel="self" />
    <item>
      **<title>Wednesday - 14:00 GMT: Not available, 11Â°C (52Â°F)</title>**
      <link>https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2647553</link>
      <description>Temperature: 11Â°C (52Â°F), Wind Direction: East South Easterly, Wind Speed: 13mph, Humidity: 58%, Pressure: 1023mb, Falling, Visibility: Excellent</description>
      <pubDate>Wed, 30 Oct 2019 14:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">https://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/2647553-2019-10-30T14:00:00.000Z</guid>
      <dc:date>2019-10-30T14:00:00Z</dc:date>
      <georss:point>51.5574 -0.1821</georss:point>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I know it is wrong but what I got until now was this :

```
XDocument X = XDocument.Load("https://weather-broker-cdn.api.bbci.co.uk/en/observation/rss/2647553");
var weather = X.Element("channel").Element("item").Element("title").Value;
weather = Regex.Match(weather, @"GMT: (.+?),").Groups[1].Value;
XmlLabel.Text = weather;
```

I really can't find anywhere where it explains it clearly,
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use Xpath to select the elements, also why not also look at the `pubDate` node or `dc:Date` node instead of trying to parse using regex, then you can get the date as an actual `DateTime` data type?

Comment: @Charleh OP is not after the Date as it seems. See https://regex101.com/r/fBSb1l/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code starts one level too deep:

`var weather = X.Element("channel").Element("item").Element("title").Value;`

You need to start from the root Element, which is "rss". So this will work:

`var weather = X.Element("rss").Element("channel").Element("item").Element("title").Value;`

But I'd recommend the shorter [XPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-query-linq-to-xml-using-xpath) variant:

`X.XPathSelectElement("//item/title").Value;`

I verified both variants above and your regex in a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eA7amr) with following code:

```
XDocument X = XDocument.Load("https://weather-broker-cdn.api.bbci.co.uk/en/observation/rss/2647553");

var test = X.XPathSelectElement("//item/title").Value;
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(test, @"GMT: (.+?),").Groups[1].Value);

var weather = X.Element("rss").Element("channel").Element("item").Element("title").Value;
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(weather, @"GMT: (.+?),").Groups[1].Value);
```

Output:

```
    Not available
    Not available
```